# Combining TWO Monte Carlo algorithms to get a Las Vegas algorithm that solves the same problem

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, monte-carlo

I came across a problem that I have no clue how to solve.

Consider two Monte Carlo algorithms, called A and B that both solve the same problem. 
A is true-biased and t-correct, while B is false-biased and z-correct.
Show that you can combine both A and B to obtain a Las Vegas algorithm to solve the same problem.

Also, how would I find the best value of R, which is the probability of the las vegas algorithm to find the right answer? For this second part, how would I find this fictional value of R with no concrete example or data set, this question seems completely out of left field.

Thank you kindly for your time :)

Comment: Run the two algorithms alternately in a certain proportion, until one of them finds a definitive answer.